# Error 405 - Method Not Found on Java HTTP function call

Tags: java, api

Need help on this piece of code. It's working fine on "POST" method. But when i changed it to "GET" for another API that accept GET method, it encounter 405 error.

P/S: I've tested the API using POSTMAN and managed to get proper respond.

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(FullURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();          
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setReadTimeout(9000);
        String input = "{\"accNo\": \"" + accNo + "\",\"token\": \"" + aToken +"\"}";   
        
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        
        Integer HTTPResponse = conn.getResponseCode();
        if(HTTPResponse != 200) 
        {
            //System.out.println("HTTP Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        char[] cbuf = new char[ 2048 ];
        int num;

        while ( -1 != (num=reader.read(cbuf)))
        {
            buf.append( cbuf, 0, num );
        }
        
        output = buf.toString();
        conn.disconnect();
        reader.close();
      }
```

Comment: How is the API method defined on the server side?

Comment: Hi, I've no visibility on the server code/log. It's managed by my client. Any error on my code?

Comment: The 405 error response tells you that the API you are using does not support the GET method. Talk to your client to clarify what method you are supposed to use.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned, I've tested using some tools to fire the webservice endpoint using GET method; and I managed to get the respond. Just need some advice on the coding level, wondering if my code causing issue.

Comment: If you have managed to make a request successfully with other tools, then yes there is something wrong with your code. Can you find what exact request these other tools made? Have you been able to determine what the difference are compared to what the Java is doing? One thing that I find weird is that you are sending a request body with a GET request - many HTTP client libraries do not support this, even if the latest version of the HTTP specification allow it.

Comment: I was trying to add request parameters to obtain the corresponding information. E.g. account number and access token.

Comment: Were you told to send these parameters in the request body, or were you told to use URL parameters? Or potentially some other form such as headers or cookies

Comment: Thanks bro, have guided me to check on the request body. I have found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue, was caused by the

```
setDoOutput(true)
```

It will implicitly set the request method to POST, since the targeted method is GET, the server will throw an 405 Method not allow error.